# How to subtract all functions on a plot by the lowest f(x) value at each x

Tags: plotting

If I have a plot with multiple functions, like so:

```
B = 1
Plot[{2 A + 20 B, 
     -18 A + 45 B, 
     1/2 (57 B - 6 Dq + Sqrt[5] Sqrt[53 B^2 - 44 B A + 20 A^2]), 
     1/2 (57 B - 6 Dq - Sqrt[5] Sqrt[53 B^2 - 44 B A + 20 A^2])}, 
     {A, 0, 6}]
```

[image: Plot of multiple functions]

How can I subtract all the functions by an amount such that the lowest y value at every point along the x axis is zero? In this case, after this scaling, the orange line would be the "minimum line" (y=0) from 0 < x < 1.52 and the yellow line would be the "minimum line" from 1.52 < x < 6. All other functions would be scaled to that "minimum line".

Comment: `B = 1; Dq = 1;
f = {2 A + 20 B, -18 A + 45 B, 
   1/2 (57 B - 6 Dq + Sqrt[5] Sqrt[53 B^2 - 44 B A + 20 A^2]), 
   1/2 (57 B - 6 Dq - Sqrt[5] Sqrt[53 B^2 - 44 B A + 20 A^2])};
Plot[Evaluate[f - Min[f]], {A, 0, 6}]`